# How to turn groupby() and value_counts() into multiple pie/bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, seaborn

Let's assume I have a dataframe and I'm looking at 2 columns of it (2 series).

Using one of the columns - `"no_employees"` below - Can someone kindly help me figure out how to create 6 different pie charts or bar charts (1 for each grouping of no_employees) that illustrate the value counts for the Yes/No values in the treatment column? I'll use `matplotlib` or `seaborn`, whatever you feel is easiest.

I'm using the attached line of code to generate the code below.

```
dataframe_title.groupby(['no_employees']).treatment.value_counts().
```

But now I'm stuck. Do I use `seaborn`? `.plot`? This seems like it should be easy, and I know there are some cases where I can make `subplots=True`, but I'm really confused. Thank you so much.

```
no_employees    treatment
1-5             Yes           88
                No            71
100-500         Yes           95
                No            80
26-100          Yes          149
                No           139
500-1000        No            33
                Yes           27
6-25            No           162
                Yes          127
More than 1000  Yes          146
                No           135
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The importance of data encoding:

1. The purpose of data visualization is to more easily convey information (e.g. in this case, the relative number of `'treatments'` per category)
2. The bar chart accommodates easily displaying the important information

   - how many in each group said `'Yes'` or `'No'`
   - the relative sizes of each group
3. A pie plot is more commonly used to display a sample, where the groups within the sample, sum to 100%.

   - [Wikipedia: Pie Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart)

     - Research has shown that comparison by angle, is less accurate than comparison by length, in that people are less able to discern differences.
     - [Statisticians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistician) generally regard pie charts as a poor method of displaying information, and they are uncommon in scientific literature.
   - This data is not well represented by a pie plot, because each company size is a separate population, which will require 6 pie plots to be **correctly** represented.
   - The data **can** be placed into a pie plot, as others have shown, but that doesn't mean it should be.

- Regardless of the type of plot, the data must be in the correct shape for the plot API.
- Tested with `pandas 1.3.0`, `seaborn 0.11.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`

---

#### Setup a test DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  # for sample data only

np.random.seed(365)
cats = ['1-5', '6-25', '26-100', '100-500', '500-1000', '>1000']

data = {'no_employees': np.random.choice(cats, size=(1000,)),
        'treatment': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'No'], size=(1000,))}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# set a categorical order for the x-axis to be ordered
df.no_employees = pd.Categorical(df.no_employees, categories=cats, ordered=True)

  no_employees treatment
0       26-100        No
1          1-5       Yes
2        >1000        No
3      100-500       Yes
4     500-1000       Yes
```

---

#### Plotting with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

- This requires grouping the dataframe to get `.value_counts`, and unstacking with [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

```py
# to get the dataframe in the correct shape, unstack the groupby result
dfu = df.groupby(['no_employees']).treatment.value_counts().unstack()

treatment     No  Yes
no_employees         
1-5           78   72
6-25          83   86
26-100        83   76
100-500       91   84
500-1000      78   83
>1000         95   91

# plot
ax = dfu.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(7, 5), xlabel='Number of Employees in Company', ylabel='Count', rot=0)
ax.legend(title='treatment', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

---

#### Plotting with `seaborn`

- [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is a high-level API for matplotlib.

##### [`seaborn.barplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

- Requires a DataFrame in a tidy (long) format, which is done by grouping the dataframe to get `.value_counts`, and resetting the index with [`pandas.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)
- May also be done with the figure-level interface using [`sns.catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='bar'`

```py
# groupby, get value_counts, and reset the index
dft = df.groupby(['no_employees']).treatment.value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')

   no_employees treatment  Count
0           1-5        No     78
1           1-5       Yes     72
2          6-25       Yes     86
3          6-25        No     83
4        26-100        No     83
5        26-100       Yes     76
6       100-500        No     91
7       100-500       Yes     84
8      500-1000       Yes     83
9      500-1000        No     78
10        >1000        No     95
11        >1000       Yes     91

# plot
p = sns.barplot(x='no_employees', y='Count', data=dft, hue='treatment')
p.legend(title='treatment', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
p.set(xlabel='Number of Employees in Company')
```

##### [`seaborn.countplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

- Uses the original dataframe, `df`, without any transformations.
- May also be done with the figure-level interface using [`sns.catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='count'`

```py
p = sns.countplot(data=df, x='no_employees', hue='treatment')
p.legend(title='treatment', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
p.set(xlabel='Number of Employees in Company')
```

- Output of `barplot` and `countplot`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's reshape the dataframe and plot with subplots=True:

```
df_chart = df1.unstack()['Pct'] 

axs = df_chart.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(4,9), layout=(2,1), legend=False, title=df_chart.columns.tolist())
ax_flat = axs.flatten()
for ax in ax_flat:
    ax.yaxis.label.set_visible(False)
```

Output:

[image]